Is making an enum public disrespecting encapsulation?
This is a question for an assignment for Uni. For this assignment we have to respect encapsulation and inheritance in Java.
The important classes to know right now are:
Cliente Class
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;

public class Cliente {

    // Definicao de enum da localizacao
    private enum Localizacao {
        CONTINENTE,
        ACORES,
        MADEIRA;
    }

    private String nome;
    private int numContribuinte;
    private Localizacao localizacao;

    public Cliente(String nome, int numContribuinte, Localizacao localizacao){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.numContribuinte = numContribuinte;
        this.localizacao = localizacao;
    }


    public Cliente() {
    }
    public void setLocalizacao(Localizacao localizacao) {
        this.localizacao = localizacao;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setNumContribuinte(int numContribuinte) {
        this.numContribuinte = numContribuinte;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getNumContribuinte() {
        return numContribuinte;
    }

    public Localizacao getLocalizacao() {
        return localizacao;
    }

    public Localizacao[] getLocalizacoes(){
        return Localizacao.values();
    }


    public void printDadosCliente() {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Dados do Cliente:");
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
        System.out.println("Número de contribuinte: " + numContribuinte);
        System.out.println("Localização do cliente: " + localizacao.name());
    }
}

the Produtos class:
public abstract class Produtos {
    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private int quantidade;
    private double valorUnitario;

    //Construtor

    public Produtos(int codigo, String nome, String descricao, int quantidade, double valorUnitario){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
    }


    // Getters
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public double getValorUnitario() {
        return valorUnitario;
    }

    public double getPrecoSemIva() {
        return valorUnitario * quantidade;
    }

    // Abstract method to calculate IVA
    public abstract double calculaIva(Cliente.Localizacao localizacao);

    public abstract void printDadosProduto();
}

and the ProdutoAlimentarNormal class, which is a subclass of ProdutoAlimentar which is a subclass of Produtos, but I omitted it as it only adds a variable to the class, isBiologic boolean:
public class ProdutoAlimentarNormal extends ProdutosAlimentares {
    public ProdutoAlimentarNormal(int codigo, String nome, String descricao, int quantidade, double valorUnitario, boolean isBiologico)
    {
        super(codigo, nome, descricao, quantidade, valorUnitario, isBiologico);
    }

    @Override
    public double calculaIva(Cliente.Localizacao localizacao){
        double taxaIva = 0.23;

        if (localizacao.equals(Cliente.Localizacao.MADEIRA)){
            taxaIva = 0.22;
        } else if (localizacao.equals(Cliente.Localizacao.ACORES)) {
            taxaIva = 0.16;
        }
        if (getBiologico()){
            taxaIva *= 0.9;
        }

        return getQuantidade()* getValorUnitario() * taxaIva;
    }

    @Override
    public void printDadosProduto(){
        System.out.println("Dados do Produto:");
        System.out.println("Tipo: Produto Alimentar");

        if (getBiologico()){
            System.out.print("Biologico: Sim");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Biologico: Não");
        }

        System.out.println("Taxa de IVA: Normal");

        System.out.println("Nome do produto: " + getNome());
        System.out.println("Código do produto: " + getCodigo());
        System.out.println("Quantidade: " + getQuantidade());
        System.out.println("Preço por unidade: " + getValorUnitario() + "€");
        System.out.println("Preço total (s/ IVA): " + getValorUnitario() * getQuantidade() + "€");
    }
}

As you can see I've set Localizacao as private:
// Definicao de enum da localizacao
private enum Localizacao {
    CONTINENTE,
    ACORES,
    MADEIRA;
}

But the IVA calculations on produtosAlimentarNormal depend on those values:
@Override
public double calculaIva(Cliente.Localizacao localizacao){
    double taxaIva = 0.23;

    if (localizacao.equals(Cliente.Localizacao.MADEIRA)){
        taxaIva = 0.22;
    } else if (localizacao.equals(Cliente.Localizacao.ACORES)) {
        taxaIva = 0.16;
    }
    if (getBiologico()){
        taxaIva *= 0.9;
    }

    return getQuantidade()* getValorUnitario() * taxaIva;
}

I tried writing it like this, passing a client instead,
@Override
public double calculaIva(Cliente cliente){
    double taxaIva = 0.13;

    if (cliente.getLocalizacao() == cliente.getLocalizacoes().NOVALUE){
        taxaIva = 0.12;
    } else if (localizacao.equals()) {
        taxaIva = 0.16;
    }
    if (categoria == CategoriasAlimentar.VINHO){
        taxaIva += 0.01;
    }

    if(getBiologico()){
        taxaIva *= 0.9;
    }

    return getQuantidade()* getValorUnitario() * taxaIva;
}

but could never get cliente.getLocalizacoes().NOVALUE to show ACORES,MADEIRA or CONTINENTE in the NOVALUE space.
Do I disrespect encapsulation by making the enum public?
I tried with various getters and setters, but could never get one that returned me something that i could just do Localizacao.ACORES whilst it being private.
Whilst it was public it worked like a charm but I'm afraid I'm not respecting encapsulation.

If callers of the public method need to know the enums, they should be public too. If they are private, they cannot be used by callers in other classes.

Fix the formatting of your code on this page. Wrapping with single back-tick is for code that is in-line within your prose. For standalone code, put your lines of code within a pair of lines that each have three back-ticks.  I fixed the first, now you can fix the others.

When posting here, strip your code down the absolute minimum needed to demonstrate your issue. Way too much code here, burying your issue rather than exposing. [MCVE]

While minimizing the code, translate the names of classes, methods, variables, etc. Don’t make us guess at its meaning.

FYI: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/  and https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Access level of parameters’ type must match or exceed that of the method
A class in OOP defines a type. This means enum classes too.
If that type is necessary as an argument in public methods, then of course that type must be public too.
You define methods such as:
public double calculaIva ( Cliente.Localizacao localizacao ) { … }

That public method takes Cliente.Localizacao object. So the Cliente.Localizacao class must be public as well. Being an enum class is irrelevant.
Whether the method calculaIva really should be public is a separate question. You should always choose the narrowest possible access that can work in your situation. See tutorial by Oracle.
You can further reduce access by employing the Java Platform Module System (JPMS).
Whatever access level you grant to a class/interface used as a parameter must match or exceed the access level of the parameter’s method.
